# What is a Facebook Timeline Unit

Tags: facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/changelog/

Facebook respond with this in their latest changelog:

*publish_action permissions will not be granted if there are no timeline units to be rendered. (rE451346)*

For the above reason I cannot request the publish_action permission in my facebook application.  My question is what the heck is a timeline unit?

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/) is a detailed discussion about [Open Graph Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/) and public actions permissions

Comment: If your app is in the games category you can request that permission and use it for publishing achievements and score updates, but for other types of app they need to also define Timeline units (see the docs linked in the main part of this answer)

Comment: I checked my category and it was set to "Video" so I changed it to "Games" and now I am getting the publish_action permission working.

Comment: Hmmm, I've chosen various different categorys and it seems Games is the only one that is enabled ... maybe they haven't fully turned on open graph for all categories?

Comment: @PazoozaTestPazman I have created aggregations but I am with others and it doesn't seem to be working? Do I really need to switch to games?